# How to read and write to CSV Files in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file, which has only a single column , which acts as my input.

I use that input to find my outputs. I have multiple outputs and I need those outputs in another csv file.

Can anyone please suggest me the ways on how to do it ?

Here is the code :

```
import urllib.request
jd = {input 1}
// 
  Some Codes to find output - a,b,c,d,e
//
** Code to write output to a csv file.
** Repeat the code with next input of input csv file.


 Input CSV File has only a single column and is represented below: 
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5 

 Output would in a separate csv in a given below format :
  It would be in multiple rows and multiple columns format.

 a    b     c    d      e
```

Comment: Your question is really vague. Use the `csv` module to load the data from the csv. Process the info and use the same module to output the data.

Comment: Actually, I am fledgling in python and dont know on how to use it. Also, I am finding to difficult to contemplate on how would it select next input from CSV after completing one iteration of operation.

Comment: Parse the files inside some folder(s) which you can handle with a simple for loop and the `os` module. Then do what I said in the first comment. Start with the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: I just posted an answer covering 3 cases (lists, pandas, numpy array). Please let us know what format do your data have in order to provide a better solution

Comment: Your first step before asking such a question is to do some research. Searching for "csv python" will  yield lots and lots of results.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah. I did that before posting the query and also implemented the methods in csv python API, but no luck . That's why I had to resort to the community.

Comment: Part of your responsibility as an asker is to _show_ the research that you did. For I don't want to waste your time or my time by recommending the csv module if you've already tried it and it didn't work for you. You need to give us some clues as to what you've already investigated so we don't point you down a road you've already been down.

Comment: If you have a csv file with a single column, why do you consider it a csv file if there are no values separated by commas?

Comment: @user3476378 I modifeid my original answer. Something like my example should work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

The data.csv is a csv with one column and multiple rows.

The results.csv contain the mean and median of the input and is a csv with 1 row and 2 columns (mean is in 1st column and median in 2nd column)

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

#load the data
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)

#calculate things for the 1st column that has the data
calculate_mean = [np.mean(data.loc[:,0])]
calculate_median = [np.median(data.loc[:,0])]
results = [calculate_mean, calculate_median]

#write results to csv
row = []
for result in results:
    row.append(result)

with open("results.csv", "wb") as file:
   writer = csv.writer(file)
   writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hey Buddy thanks, I had a query that -  I have one csv file, which has a single column with multiple rows. For Each row, I am doing operation, and finding some outputs. Those outputs are needed to saved in separate csv file in multiple columns. And I want to repeat this until my input csv file gets finished.

Comment: Really appreciated help. !! I just a way to approach . some pseudocode as you have written in your answer.

Comment: @user3476378 do you use pandas to load the first csv file? also, your results are lists or numpy arrays?

Comment: Hi, I havent used anything yet. I came to know that csv and pandas are both go to API's to do these things.

Comment: @user3476378 I will edit my original answer in few minutes adding some code and a simple example.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. meanwhile, I have also edited the question and added how my input csv looks and how my output csv would look like.

Comment: @user3476378 I modified my answer. It does what you want. The results.csv has columns for each a,b,c you calculate.

Comment: Thanks for providing the framework. It really much clears the air of doubt I had.!

Comment: @user3476378 I am glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for reading file to `Series` and [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for writing output `Series` to file in looping by [`Series.iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html).

---

```
#file content
1
3
5
```

---

```
s = pd.read_csv('file', squeeze=True, names=['a'])
print (s)
0    1
1    3
2    5
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

---

```
for i, val in s.iteritems():
    #print (val)
    #some operation with scalar value val
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(val)})
    df['a'] = df['a'] * 10
    print (df)
    #write to csv, file name by val
    df.to_csv(str(val) + '.csv', index=False)

   a
0  0

    a
0   0
1  10
2  20

    a
0   0
1  10
2  20
3  30
4  40
```

Comment: and how would I import from CSV and how would the code use the input value , writes to csv and then moves back to pick another input value ? I am really confused.

Comment: Hmmm, do you have multiple one column input files and need one output file with all columns ?

Comment: because then is pandas not necessary, plain python is better/faster. But if need create `DataFrame` (2d array) from all data and then process them by pandas functions, then use my solution.

Comment: I have one csv file, which has a single column with multiple rows. For Each row, I am doing operation, and finding some outputs. Those outputs are needed to saved in separate csv file in multiple columns. And  I want to repeat this until my input csv file gets finished.

Comment: @user3476378 can you upload your data in order to find a solution?

Comment: I have added the sample look of csv in the question itself.

Comment: @user3476378 - my solution can be used, only question is how create output file from input row (`val`)?

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks for providing the framework.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code, you'll do something like this:

```
for each_file in a_folder_that_contains_csv:  # go through all the `inputs` - csv files
    with open(each_file) as csv_file, open(other_file) as output_file:  # open each csv file, and a new csv file
        process_the_input_from_each_csv  # process the data you read from the csv_file
        export_to_output_file  # export the data to the new csv file
```

Now, I won't write a full-working example because it's better for you to start digging and ask *specific* questions when you have some. You're now just asking: *write this for me because I don't know Python*.

- [here is the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)
- [here you can read about the csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
- [here you can read about the `os` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Comment: Hey Thanks, I have taken your advice. I dont needed anyone to code for me. I just needed a way on how to approach this.